# Grab name of variable dynamically in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to know how to grab the name of a variable in Ansible. I have seen multiple posts about dynamically building variable names from values of other variables with the vars lookup, but I do not want the value of a known variable, I want to get the name of an unknown variable in a list.

Say I have a list as such:

```yaml
host_inputs: 
  - host1_name: 
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
  - host2_name:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
  - host3_name:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
  - host4_name:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
```

While iterating over the list of dictionaries I would like to grab the name of each one `host1_name` then `host2_name` to use. This is for taking in values for hosts with their respective variables to build an AWX inventory, but I will not know the host names ahead of time.

I know I can just iterate over the `"{{ host_inputs }}"` to get each dictionary to assign those variables to the respective group, but I need the name of the dictionary, or `"{{ item }}"` for that loop iteration to use to name the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, your data structure seems convoluted in regards to your requirements.

A, possibly, better structure here would be to use a dictionary where each host would be the keys:

```yaml
host_inputs: 
  host1_name: 
    var1: value1
    var2: value2
  host2_name:
    var1: value1
    var2: value2
# shortened to two hosts for brevity in this whole answer
```

This way, you would simply have to use the [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html) filter, which will produce normalised a list of `key`/`value` out of a dictionary:

```yaml
host_inputs | dict2items:
  - key: host1_name
    value:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
  - key: host2_name
    value:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
```

---

This said, if you cannot change your actual data structure, you can apply the `dict2items` filter to all the elements of your list — thanks to [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) — then flatten it:

```yaml
host_inputs | map('dict2items') | flatten:
  - key: host1_name
    value:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
  - key: host2_name
    value:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
```

---

As an example, both the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: _loop
  vars:
    _loop: "{{ host_inputs | dict2items }}"
    host_inputs:
      host1_name:
        var1: value1
        var2: value2
      host2_name:
        var1: value1
        var2: value2
```

And the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: _loop
  vars:
    _loop: "{{ host_inputs | map('dict2items') | flatten }}"
    host_inputs:
      - host1_name:
          var1: value1
          var2: value2
      - host2_name:
          var1: value1
          var2: value2
```

Would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  _loop:
  - key: host1_name
    value:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
  - key: host2_name
    value:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  hi: "{{ dict(host_inputs|map('dict2items')|
               json_query('[].[key, value]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  hi:
    host1_name:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
    host2_name:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
    host3_name:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
```

Then, use the dictionary instead of creating a new variable for each item.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    host_inputs: 
      - host1_name: 
          var1: value1
          var2: value2
      - host2_name:
          var1: value1
          var2: value2
      - host3_name:
          var1: value1
          var2: value2

    hi: "{{ dict(host_inputs|map('dict2items')|
                 json_query('[].[key, value]')) }}"
          
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hi
```

---

Notes:

- Optionally, use [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables).  For example, given the inventory for testing

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host1_name var1=value11 var2=value12
host2_name var1=value21 var2=value22
host3_name var1=value31 var2=value32
```

the below expression

```yaml
  hostvars.host2_name.var2
```

gives

```yaml
  hostvars.host2_name.var2: value22
```

- Optionally, create the dictionary instead of the list. For example, the below expressions

```yaml
  hi: "{{ dict(hostvars|dict2items|json_query(hi_query)) }}"
  hi_query: '[].[key, {var1: value.var1, var2: value.var2}]'
```

give

```yaml
  hi:
    host1_name:
      var1: value11
      var2: value12
    host2_name:
      var1: value21
      var2: value22
    host3_name:
      var1: value31
      var2: value32
```

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hi: "{{ dict(hostvars|dict2items|json_query(hi_query)) }}"
    hi_query: '[].[key, {var1: value.var1, var2: value.var2}]'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hostvars.host2_name.var2
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: hi
      run_once: true
```